# Find $a, b, c$ such that element $x=a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3+x+11 \rangle$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, wolfram-alpha, sagemath

I'm trying to generate a fundamental unit of the number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where  $\alpha^3+\alpha+11$.
I found a non-trivial unit and I need to find $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that 
$$\frac{(-5\alpha^2-4\alpha+8)(6\alpha^2+6)(10\alpha^2+10\alpha)}{(8\alpha^2+8\alpha)^6(9\alpha^2+9\alpha)^{11}(10\alpha^2)}= a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c.$$
Does anyone know how to compute $a, b, c$ on Wolfram alpha or Sagemath?

Comment: Not an answer as you're looking for help with WolframAlpha or Sagemath, but note that
$$\alpha(\alpha^2+1)=-11,$$
so $\alpha^{-1}=-\tfrac{1}{11}(\alpha^2+1)$ and similary
$$(\alpha+1)(\alpha^2-\alpha+2)=-9,$$
so $(\alpha+1)^{-1}=-\tfrac19(\alpha^2-\alpha+2)$. Substituting these makes your expression a polynomial in $\alpha$, and then long division yields $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search leads to [the "Number field element" page of the Sage documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field_element.html), which shows that the following code does the trick in SageMath:

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^3 + x + 11)
f = a.coordinates_in_terms_of_powers()
f((-5*a^2-4*a+8)*(6*a^2+6)*(8*a^2+8)^(-6)*(9*a^2+9*a)^(-11)*(10*a^2)^(-1)*(10*a^2+10*a))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we define the number field `K` defined by the degree three
polynomial in the question, with `a` as a generator, then Sage
automatically expresses elements in `K` as polynomials in `a`.

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3+x+11)
sage: n = (-5*a^2 - 4*a + 8) * (6*a^2 + 6) * (10*a^2 + 10*a)
sage: d = (8*a^2 + 8)^6 * (9*a^2 + 9*a)^11 * (10*a^2)
sage: u = n/d
sage: u
-37655851421063/7501767430252463720585645819465760768*a^2
+ 3549027946847/340989428647839260026620264521170944*a
- 399196880586881/15003534860504927441171291638931521536
```

The answer by @Servaes is useful to get a list of coefficients
instead of a polynomial in `a`.

Note that in that list, the coefficients are ordered by increasing
powers of `a`: first the coefficient of `a^0` (i.e. the constant
coefficient), then of `a^1`, then of `a^2`.

Another way to get those, without using the
`coordinates_in_terms_of_powers` method, is as follows:

```
sage: u.polynomial().coefficients()
[-399196880586881/15003534860504927441171291638931521536,
 3549027946847/340989428647839260026620264521170944,
 -37655851421063/7501767430252463720585645819465760768]
```